# Is there an easyJet ticket office in Schönefeld?

Tags: tickets, berlin, easyjet, sxf

I have been to Schönefeld a few times before, but I cannot remember:

Is there an easyJet stand or an office where I could buy my ticket (in advance, I mean) using cash or a German ATM card?

I don't have a credit card so I can't buy online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an EasyJet Customer Service desk where I had to go to change my flight because I had just missed the one I had originally booked. They handled everything there and printed me a new boarding pass, so I presume you could book a ticket there too. Whether they take cash or not is a different matter, so it'd be best to go there beforehand to find out.

You can find the desk on the ground floor near the EasyJet baggage check-in area. It's right in the corner, and there's usually a helpful person standing around you can ask if you can't find it - it's not immediately obvious.

Comment: I found an alternative solution, but I chose your answer because it answers my original question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

I don't remember one either but it seems you can [book online and pay by bank transfer](http://www.easyjet.com/de/zahlung-elektronischen-lastschriftverfahren-de) instead.

Comment: I wish I had seen this earlier, but I'm booking a flight in less than two weeks!

Answer (score 6):

It's not directly an answer to your question, but an alternative (easier!) solution to your problem might be to ask a friend or family member who does have a credit or debit card to buy it. There is no problem with an Easyjet flight being bought on a card in another person's name, I do it all the time when travelling for work.

Comment: I'm always reluctant when it comes to ask friends or family for money and/or their credit cards... In the end I solved the issue taking a completely different approach and travelling by bus!